# Splitting a string before the nth occurrence of a character

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have a string

```
s = '"Never you mind what it is!" the guard retorted. "What are you?"'
```

I want to split it into 2 different quotes

```
s1 = '"Never you mind what it is!" the guard retorted.'
s2 = '"What are you"'
```

It needs to split the string before the 3rd ' " '

Comment: Is it always 3rd occurence?

Comment: Answered already here.. For shame!

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string)